# php timestamp mysqli bind_param select like

Tags: php, mysqli, data-binding

How to set bind_param values for timestamp (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ) in a

```
select * from mytable where date like=?
```

i tried it with an integer but than like is not working.

Comment: "Not working". How? Show us what you want to do, what you have tried, and what results you get.

Answer (score 0):

```
$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
"SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE date='$date'";
```

Comment: i need it with a like

Comment: SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y %m') = DATE_FORMAT('2012-01-01', '%Y %m')
ORDER BY date